# Не могу найти оплошность,должен выводить числа от большего к меньшему,а делает наоборот

Tags: массивы, pascal

````
```
program programb;
var
mas: array [1..100] of integer;
i,j,r,a,b,c,d,e,f,h,k,l,m,N: integer;
begin
write('Введите размерность массива',' ');
  readln(N);
Write('Введите 1 элемент массива',' ');
  Readln(a);
Write('Введите 2 элемент массива',' '); 
  Readln(b);
Write('Введите 3 элемент массива',' '); 
  Readln(c);
Write('Введите 4 элемент массива',' ');
  Readln(d);
Write('Введите 5 элемент массива',' '); 
  Readln(e);
Write('Введите 6 элемент массива',' ');
  Readln(f);
Write('Введите 7 элемент массива',' ');
  Readln(h);
Write('Введите 8 элемент массива', ' ');
  Readln(k);
Write('Введите 9 элемент массива',' ');
  Readln(l);
Write('Введите 10 элемент массива',' '); 
Readln(m);

 mas[1]:=a;
 mas[2]:=b;
 mas[3]:=c;
 mas[4]:=d;
 mas[5]:=e;
 mas[6]:=f;
 mas[7]:=h;
 mas[8]:=k;
 mas[9]:=l;
 mas[10]:=m;
  for i:=1 to N-1 do 
    for j:= 1 to N-i do 
      if (mas[j]>mas[j+1] ) then
        begin 
          r := mas[j];    
          mas[j] :=mas[j+1];
          mas[j+1] :=r;
          end;
          for i:=1 to 10 do
            write(mas[i],' ');
end.      
```
[окно вывода][1]
````

Comment: Вы вводите размерности массива. А потом всего десять элементов, причём в переменные. Надо цикл и `readln(mas[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использованная сортировка пузырьком сортирует по убыванию.

Для того, чтобы результат был по возрастанию, достаточно изменить знак в сравнении в условии if.

---

Кроме того, куча переменных для ввода не нужна - можно в цикле читать сразу в

```
Readln(mas[i]);
```